# Why is this MySQL select query slowing things down?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE post_deleted='0'"
```

I can see via New Relic that it's eating up 60% of my MySQL resources, and therefore slowing down my entire website.

I have no idea why such a simple query would slow anything down? My table is an `InnoDB` table, with index on "id".

Comment: you need an index on post_deleted as well

Comment: And if `post_deleted` is a string where you have it only as a number, try switching the data type.  Giving the DB structure would help too as you may have other optimization options.

Comment: post_deleted int(1)   NOT NULL Standard Value: 0

Comment: how many posts are in table `forum_posts` ? if its more than 100 maybe a [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) would help ?

Comment: @Bor691 there is 5000+ rows..

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch 5K+ rows in one go? Surely you don't intend to render all those things in a web application?

Comment: depends on what do you want to do with all the data , i don't think you want to display all 5000+ rows on one page , do you ? if you limit the scope of query results to the number of rows you need it will be faster and consume less resources because less data is transferred from mysql to php.

Comment: @halfer I am selecting from the table, that has 5000+ rows. How should I do it?

Comment: Paginate the table in your user interface, and then you only need select 50 rows at a time (or whatever other small number you choose).

Comment: @oliverbj lets say you want to fetch first 100 rows , you do `select * from forum_posts WHERE post_deleted=0 LIMIT 0,100` that is `limit Start,Length` (more on this in the link on my first comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create index on `post_deleted`
- Verify that `post_deleted` is of type boolean (tinyint, smallint, or even integer will outperform string)
- Don't compare against the string '0' but against the number 0.

Comment: What about adding a limit, would that help?

Comment: The performance of the query in this case has nothing to do with the amount of data that gets transfered to output. For any client performance, however, the time spent in transfering the data add up for the total processing time. I thought you said newrelic was alerting you on the DB performance.